# Basis in Hilbert C* module

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $X$ is a Hilbert right module over a C* algebra $B$ and a right B valued inner product $\langle , \rangle_B$ you consider the case where the adjointable are the same as the compact operators we can find a set $\{u_i,v_i\}$ such that for any $x$ in $X$
$$x=\sum_i u_i \langle v_i,x\rangle$$
(this follows just by writing the identity map as a compact). Apparently from this it follows that one can find another set $\{w_i\}$ such that one can write instead:
$$x=\sum_i w_i\langle w_i,x \rangle$$

I tried to write $v_i$ in terms of the first formula but i don't seem to get this set $w_i$. Due to some calculations I made I was able to show that if the compact operator $\theta_{v,v}$ is positive for any $v \in X$ then this follows, but I don't see why this compact operator should be positive.

Recall $\theta_{v,w}(x)=v\langle w,x \rangle$

Comment: Are these claims from some reference?  If so, would you please share it?

Comment: Yes these are claims from the following paper by kajiwara and watatani  (See Lemma 1.7) https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2000-352-08/S0002-9947-00-02392-8/S0002-9947-00-02392-8.pdf

Comment: We have $$\langle y, \theta^*_{v,v}(z) \rangle = \langle \theta_{v,v}(y), z \rangle = \langle v \langle v, y \rangle, z \rangle = \langle v, y \rangle^* \langle v, z \rangle = \langle y, v \rangle \langle v, z \rangle = \langle y, v\langle v, z \rangle \rangle = \langle y, \theta_{v, v}(z) \rangle,$$ so $\theta_{v,v}$ is self-adjoint.

We also have $$\langle x, \theta_{v,v}(x) \rangle = \langle x, v\langle v, x \rangle \rangle = \langle v, x \rangle^* \langle v, x \rangle \ge 0.$$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by positive here, but the last line of my previous comment would be sufficient to prove positivity for a scalar-valued inner product.  Not sure for the $B$-valued case, though.